# Hazelcast - .Net Client support for reliable topic?

Tags: java, .net, distributed-computing, publish-subscribe, hazelcast

I am trying to use Hazelcast reliable topic from .Net Client.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Reliable_Topic.html

Is there support for it?

From java client I have below methods:

```
ITopic<MyObject> topic = hazelcastInstance.getTopic(topicName);

ITopic<MyObject> topic = hazelcastInstance.getReliableTopic(topicName);
```

But from .Net Client I only have :

```
 var topic = client.GetTopic<MyObject>(topicName);
```

I would also expect the below method:

```
var topic = client.GetReliableTopic<MyObject>(topicName);
```

I am using Hazelcast.Net -Version 3.9.2.

When I publish to reliable topic, I could not find a way to receive it from .net client..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clients comparison page lists the features available per client. See here for .NET https://hazelcast.org/clients/net/ or here https://hazelcast.org/clients-languages/